# How to install the Taurus framework in a Windows 10 machine without internet connection?

Tags: jmeter-plugins, taurus

I would like to install the Taurus framework in a Windows 10 machine without internet connection and use it to run some jmeter scripts. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126)
3. Install Taurus using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) like:

   ```
   pip install bzt
   ```
4. Download [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)
5. If your test is using [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) and use it to get all the plugins you need
6. Copy whole Python installation to your Windows 10 machine
7. Copy JMeter installation to your Windows 10 machine and drop it under `%USERPROFILE\.bzt\jmeter-taurus\5.4.1` (you might need to replace it with your own JMeter version)
8. Add `Scripts` folder of your Python installation to your system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

Comment: please note you will need to update the most recent VS tools...that link is outdated